# firebase auth , persistence of user not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is the context

```
export default function UserAuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  async function logIn(email, password) {
    try {
      await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
      return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, logIn }}>
      {children}
    </UserAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and this is the protected route that i am using to show the Home page of my app

```
function Protected({ children }) {
  const { user } = useContext(UserAuthContext);
  console.log(user);
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

but even after this the moment i refresh my page i get logged out.
***********please help me**********

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are observing that the user is signed out.  Certainly there will be more code to show where you are making this check that we can use to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: In the firebase docs , it's only written to do this. I dont know which part to show , as the code base is huge I am using the onAuthChange method  to show whether a user is signed in or not . Can you tell me how it is done , a little bit guide only

Comment: Where are you running this code. On most browser based environments, Firebase already persists user credentials by default and you don't need to do anything for that yourself.

Comment: I am running this on firefox and that is not persisting.

Comment: Your profile tells that you are an expert in Firebase so please help

Comment: I asked you to show the code that illustrates how you are observing the fact that the user is signed out.  All you are showing right now is how you sign in the user, not how you see what executes on browser refresh that suggests they are no longer signed in.  We can't see that you might be doing something wrong (you are probably doing something wrong).  Please read about how to create a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to reproduce the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I am sorrty now that I am updated my question can you please tell me what is the problem here???